# Page Header overlaping content when using Rotativa to generate PDF from HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am try to convert an `HTML file` to PDF using "Rotativa" lib, but i am facing some problems when using custom headers, here is my code:

```
string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html  \"{0}\" " +
                               "--header-spacing \"0\" " +
                               "--footer-html \"{1}\" " +
                               "--footer-spacing \"10\" " +
                               "--footer-font-size \"10\" " +
                               "--header-font-size \"10\" ", header, footer);

            var invoice = new ViewAsPdf("Index", _invoiceRepository.GetInvoice(1))
            {
                FileName = "MyPDF.pdf",
                CustomSwitches = customSwitches,
                PageMargins = margin,
                PageSize = size,
                PageOrientation = orientation                
            };

            return invoice;
```

The headers and Footers are being successfully injected on the top and bottom of each page like expected but the problem is that the header is **overlapping** that rest of the content.
how can i reserve space for the header?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar trouble when setting `--header-spacing \"0\"` once. So the solution that worked for me was to set higher spacing between header and content.

Please try setting, for example, spacing to 7 (measure is given in mm, as you can review in [WkHtmlToPdf documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)). This way, you can check current PDF with one you have generated before, and verify if change solves the problem. Once there, you should be ablo to adjust the measure to the value that is suitable for you.

So, your code should look like:

```
string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html  \"{0}\" " +
                           "--header-spacing \"7\" " +
                           "--footer-html \"{1}\" " +
                           "--footer-spacing \"10\" " +
                           "--footer-font-size \"10\" " +
                           "--header-font-size \"10\" ", header, footer);
```

I tried your code in one of my projects and seems to work fine.

Hope it would be of help. If trouble continues, it should be useful to inlcude some samples os your HTML header and PDF body content, to chek the specific case.